# HTML/JS - Save data-* for later use

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

*Background*: I'm currently working on a library coordinate system as `HTML-canvas`. Currently the *user* is able to use it just by adding a `div`-element of specific class. He should be able to customize the system with `data-*` attributes on the `div`-element.

I need to access this data frequently (for example on *resize*). I loop over an array of all `div`s with said class (returned by `document.getElementsByClassName`) and read the data with `element.getAttribute(name)` to resize the elements and do further operations. I think it's not that efficient to always *again* read the data (every resize) and use it. What would be a good way (good practice/ efficient) to store the data and access it at any time?

I was thinking about an array. I could write an `init()`-function, which would load all data into objects with one property for each `data-*` element and one extra element to hold the `HTML`-element itself.
On resize I could loop over all the objects in the array and do my operations...

Since I'm new to javascript I'm happy about any help I can get. What do you think about this approach?

Comment: do the attribs change after load ? if not, then use an array and use one `data-` to store an index to that array of objects to find the data associated with the element. if you always need to do all of them, you don't even need the index...

Comment: @dandavis The data does not change, so it's fine without index. If you'd write a small answer I would be happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save `document.getElementsByClassName` as an array, accessing data attributes on them is just retrieving a property on the object.  It's just locating the elements on the DOM that takes time.  As long as you store that array, looping through it is quick.

Comment: Okay, greta - I'll go with the array.

Comment: What do you think about [this (jsfiddle)?](https://jsfiddle.net/xmshwrgt/6/)

Comment: @LastSecondsToLive the fiddle doesn't work (Chrome PC), don't you need to establish context with `getContext()` or something?

Comment: If you mean the text `Unfortunately... `  - that is on propose. The code is not intended to draw anything. It's about the managing.